# Adding outputs from a for loop into a data.frame so i can graph them with ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, simulation

I want to calculate the populous of a prey-predator system after a consistent time period , for this i have i have created my code based on this formula:
[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEjF5.png)

The code in r:

```
matrixA <- matrix(c(0.4,-0.5,0.3,1.2),nrow = 2) #population change matrix
basepop <- matrix(c(10,30),nrow = 2)            #base population

plot(basepop[1,1],basepop[2,1])
for(k in 1:50){
population <- matrixA %*% basepop  #population[1,2] - predator
basepop <- population              #population[2,1] - prey
  print(population)

}
```

Now i just want to add the results from this loop into a data frame where the x coordinate tells the population of the predator and y coordinate that of the prey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similiar to the answer by @JustinCocco but a bit different.

1. I make population a matrix with the number of cols equal to the number of simulation periods
2. I do the conversion to a data frame after finishing the simulation.

```r
matrixA <- matrix(c(0.4,-0.5,0.3,1.2),nrow = 2) #population change matrix
basepop <- matrix(c(10,30),nrow = 2)            #base population

# Init matrix
population <- matrix(NA, nrow = 2, ncol = 50)
population[,1] <- basepop
for(k in 2:50) {
  population[,k] <- matrixA %*% population[,k-1]
}

# Make dataframe
population_df <- data.frame(k = seq(ncol(population)), predator = population[1,], prey = population[2,])

# Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(population_df, aes(predator, prey, color = k)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh this is nice, nice touch with adding the k-value.

Comment: Thank both of you very much for the quick answer.

Comment: If you dont mind can you show me how to center the graph to 0 so it can show both negative x, y axis.

Comment: You can set the limits with e.g. `coord_cartesian` like so: `+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-1, 1) * max(population_df$predator), ylim = c(-1, 1) * max(population_df$prey))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add each iteration of the population matrix into a data frame for plotting:

```
matrixA <- matrix(c(0.4,-0.5,0.3,1.2),nrow = 2) #population change matrix
basepop <- matrix(c(10,30),nrow = 2)            #base population

plot(basepop[1,1],basepop[2,1])
continued.df <- data.frame("predator" = rep(NA, times = 50), "prey" = rep(NA, times = 50))
for(k in 1:50){
  population <- matrixA %*% basepop  #population[1,2] - predator
  basepop <- population       #population[2,1] - prey
  print(population)
  continued.df$prey[k] <- population[2]
  continued.df$predator[k] <- population[1]
}
plot(continued.df)
```

Then plotting `continued.df` will give you the predator on the `x` and prey on the `y` (Assuming I understood you correctly: the prey population starts out at 30 and the predator at 10.